# Permanent solution for Debian XFCE missing desktop

Tags: linux, debian, debian-stretch

I have Debian 9 running with XFCE desktop. However, after a while, the desktop when missing. This happened to me while using Debian 10 also. My solution was to use `xfdesktop -R` in terminal and restart the desktop. But I am having to run this command pretty often. Is there anyway to do a complete fix to my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to the question. I updated the BIOS of the computer. This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqDUCfU-e-A) might help you if you are doing it [linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqDUCfU-e-A).

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael